# getElementByID.innerhtml in textfield

Tags: innerhtml, getelementbyid

Can someone tell me how I can get the getelementid.innerHTML value into the textfield?

Look at page here: http://studiodms.com/qoresneaker/ma.php

Comment: There's multiple textfields and various other things going on in that page.  Post the markup in the question and try a tool that helps you create simplified examples instead, http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Usually one sets the value of a text field with
 `document.getElementById("yourId").value = newValue` 
you can also get the value in that way as well.

Comment: Can you look at my code and tell me what I have to do. I'm not a coder, and I'm just hacking the code away. Thanks

Comment: @user1607713 As Mackey stated you need to tells us what text field and how you expected it to work. As well as what you have tried. You really should put some effort into your solving your question. This isn't a code for free environment.

Comment: @user1607713 - Going from knowing nothing to setting values across various controls in a webpage is far too large a bridge to cross in a Q&A forum such as this.  You need to learn the basics first.  Then come back with specific questions.

Comment: Pretty much the same values that are dynamically updated in the yellow area, I want them to appear in the textfields as well.
I tried using id="lat" in the textfields, but it did not pull the any data the same way <td> does.